# Vertices not aligning

Tags: vertices

I don't know how this is happening, but I just create a shape, scale it and then the vertices are not aligning. Any help is appreciate.

Here is an step by step process and a link to the video of it:

1. Create cube
2. Make it multiresolution
3. Scale it
4. Zoom view to sides and front
5. See the vertices not aligning
6. Get frustrated

[Youtube video of my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oet9hJyai_w&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

This problem shouldn't harm your model in anyway, but if you want to fix it you should do the following:

1. Click on the drop-down next to the magnet, hot-key = Control + Shift + Tab:[image]
2. Select the following options: Increment, Scale. It doesn't matter if you have selected Move and/or Rotate:
   [image]
3. Click the magnet to activate snapping, hot-key = Shift + Tab. I don't have a picture for this, if you need it you can tell me. Instead of clicking the magnet, you can also hold Control while scaling.

Comment: I am sorry, but it did not work. I applied those changes and then did the same exercise and still the same.